# Java Hangman Game

Tags: java, swing

Hi I've been making a hangman game in Java over ther holidays. Im almost done, but i'm having a few problems with repainting/updating the window.

So when ever a life is lost, I'm removing the panel and then adding another one, but for some reason it keeps shifting to the left or sometimes to the right, which means some of my lines are n't being redrawn.

edit: I'm still having trouble, I think I will just leave it now, unless anyone else has some other suggestions.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;

/** class to display a JFrame object using border layout */

public class HangmanJFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

 private JPanel centerPanel;
 private JPanel southPanel;
 private JTextField textField;
 private LinePanel line;
 private String [] wordList = {"computer","java","activity","alaska","appearance","article",
   "automobile","basket","birthday","canada","central","character","chicken","chosen",
   "cutting","daily","darkness","diagram","disappear","driving","effort","establish","exact",
   "establishment","fifteen","football","foreign","frequently","frighten","function","gradually",
   "hurried","identity","importance","impossible","invented","italian","journey","lincoln",
   "london","massage","minerals","outer","paint","particles","personal","physical","progress",
   "quarter","recognise","replace","rhythm","situation","slightly","steady","stepped",
   "strike","successful","sudden","terrible","traffic","unusual","volume","yesterday" };

 public ArrayList<String> usedLetters = new ArrayList(); // list of used letter by user
 public ArrayList<String> correctLetters = new ArrayList();
 public String userInput = "";

 private int numLives = 6; // number of lives
 public String theWord; // the wrong which is chosen
 JButton exitButton;
 JButton playAgain;

 // no-argument constructor
 public HangmanJFrame() { 
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  theWord = pickWord();
  correctLetters = new ArrayList(theWord.length());

  setSize(600,500);
  setLocation(100, 100);
  setTitle("Hangman Game");
  setLayout(new BorderLayout());

  centerPanel = new JPanel();
  line = new LinePanel(15,theWord,usedLetters);
  centerPanel.setSize(500,500);
  centerPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
  centerPanel.add(line);
  add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

  textField = new JTextField(20);
  textField.addActionListener(this);

  playAgain = new JButton("Play Again");
  exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
  exitButton.addActionListener(this);
  playAgain.addActionListener(this);

  southPanel = new JPanel();
  southPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
  southPanel.setLayout(new  GridLayout(0,3));
  southPanel.add(playAgain);
  southPanel.add(textField);
  southPanel.add(exitButton);
  add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

 }

 // Picks a word, latter it will be picked randomly.
 private String pickWord(){
  return wordList[0];
 }

 // This method check wither the input is valid
 // i.e. its in the alphabet.
 private boolean checkInput(String s){
  String [] alphabet = {"a","b","c","d","e","f",
    "g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p",
    "q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};

  for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++){
   if (s.equals(alphabet[i]) && s.length() <= 1){
    return true;
   }
  }
  return false;
 }

 /**
  * 
  */
 public void Play(){


  if (numLives > 0){

   if (userInput.length() == 1 && usedLetters.contains(userInput) == false &&
     checkInput(userInput) == true){
    usedLetters.add(userInput);

    if (theWord.contains(userInput) == true){
     correctLetters.add(userInput);
     centerPanel.removeAll();

     line = new LinePanel(20,theWord,correctLetters);
     centerPanel.add(line);
     centerPanel.revalidate();
    }

    else{
     numLives = numLives - 1;

     centerPanel.removeAll();
     line = new LinePanel(numLives,theWord,correctLetters);

     centerPanel.add(line);
     centerPanel.revalidate();
    }
   }

   else if (userInput.length() > 1)
    System.out.println("Enter a valid letter");

   else if (userInput.length() == 1 && checkInput(userInput) == true && theWord.contains(userInput)){
    correctLetters.add(userInput);
   }

   centerPanel.removeAll();

   line = new LinePanel(20,theWord,usedLetters);
   centerPanel.add(line);
   centerPanel.revalidate();
  }  
}
 // return true if the word and the correctly used letters list match
 public boolean checkWord(String s, ArrayList<String> t){
  String temp = "";

  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
   if ( t.contains(s.substring(i, i+1)) == true){
    temp += s.substring(i, i+1);
   }
  }

  if (s.equals(temp)){
   return true;
  }

  return false;
 }

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
  String temp = textField.getText();
  if (temp.length() == 1){
   userInput = temp;
  }
  textField.selectAll();
  if (checkWord(theWord, correctLetters) != true){
   Play();
  }

  if (evt.getSource() == exitButton){
   System.exit(0);
  }

//  if (evt.getSource() == playAgain){
//   removeAll();
//   repaint();
//   
//  }

 }


}

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class LinePanel extends JPanel {

 int x = 5;
 String theWord = "";
 ArrayList<String> letterList;

 public LinePanel(int num, String t, ArrayList<String> s) {
  super(); // 300,350
  setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
  setBackground(Color.RED);
  this.x = num;
  this.theWord = t;
  letterList = cloneList(s);
 }

 private ArrayList<String> cloneList(ArrayList<String> aList) {
  ArrayList<String> clonedList = new ArrayList<String>(aList.size());
  for (String letter : aList) 
   clonedList.add(letter);
  return clonedList;
 }



 public int getX() {
  return x;
 }

 public void setX(int x) {
  this.x = x;
 }

 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
  if (x == 15 || x != 15){
   Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(0, 250, 80, 250); // Creates base
   Line2D line2 = new Line2D.Double(40, 50, 40, 250); // Creates vertical line
   Line2D line3 = new Line2D.Double(40, 50, 150, 50); // Creates horizontal line
   Line2D line4 = new Line2D.Double(150, 50, 150, 80); // Creates small line to hang the man
   g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5.0f)); // Line thickness
   g2.setColor(Color.BLACK); // Line colour

   //draw shape of line
   g2.draw(line);
   g2.draw(line2);
   g2.draw(line3);
   g2.draw(line4);

   int x1 = 0; int y = 320;
   for (int i = 0; i < theWord.length();i++){
    g2.drawLine(x1, y, x1 + 20, y);
    x1 += 50;
   }
  }

  // head
  if (x == 5 || x < 5){
   System.out.println("uheuheuha");
   g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5.0f));
   g2.drawOval(135, 85, 35, 35);
  }

  // body
  if (x == 4 || x < 4){
   g2.drawLine(150, 120, 150, 190);
  }

  // left arm
  if (x == 3 || x < 3){
   g2.drawLine(150, 140, 125, 155); 
  }

  // right arm
  if (x == 2 || x < 2){
   g2.drawLine(150, 140, 175, 155); 
  }

  // left leg and foot
  if (x == 1 || x < 1){
   g2.drawLine(150, 190, 125, 200); // leg
   g2.drawLine(125, 200, 120, 190); // foot
  }

  // right leg and foot
  if (x == 0){
   g2.drawLine(150, 190, 175, 200); // leg
   g2.drawLine(175, 200, 180, 190); // foot
  }

  // Show whole word on screen
  if (x == 20){

   int x1 = 3; int y = 317;

   String temp = "";

   for (int i = 0; i < theWord.length(); i++){
    if ( letterList.contains(theWord.substring(i, i+1)) == true){
     temp += theWord.substring(i, i+1);
    }
    else{
     temp += " ";
    }
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < temp.length() ;i++){
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 25);
    g2.setFont(font);
    g2.drawString(temp.substring(i, i+1), x1, y);
    x1 += 50;
   }


   x1 = 3;  y = 370;
   for (int i = 0; i < letterList.size() ;i++){

    if (theWord.contains(letterList.get(i)) == false){
     g2.drawString(letterList.get(i), x1, y );
     x1 += 50;
    }

   }


  }
 }
}

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class LinePanel extends JPanel {

 int x = 5;
 String theWord = "";
 ArrayList<String> letterList;

 public LinePanel(int num, String t, ArrayList<String> s) {
  super(); // 300,350
  setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
  setBackground(Color.RED);
  this.x = num;
  this.theWord = t;
  letterList = cloneList(s);
 }

 private ArrayList<String> cloneList(ArrayList<String> aList) {
  ArrayList<String> clonedList = new ArrayList<String>(aList.size());
  for (String letter : aList) 
   clonedList.add(letter);
  return clonedList;
 }



 public int getX() {
  return x;
 }

 public void setX(int x) {
  this.x = x;
 }

 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
  if (x == 15 || x != 15){
   Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(0, 250, 80, 250); // Creates base
   Line2D line2 = new Line2D.Double(40, 50, 40, 250); // Creates vertical line
   Line2D line3 = new Line2D.Double(40, 50, 150, 50); // Creates horizontal line
   Line2D line4 = new Line2D.Double(150, 50, 150, 80); // Creates small line to hang the man
   g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5.0f)); // Line thickness
   g2.setColor(Color.BLACK); // Line colour

   //draw shape of line
   g2.draw(line);
   g2.draw(line2);
   g2.draw(line3);
   g2.draw(line4);

   int x1 = 0; int y = 320;
   for (int i = 0; i < theWord.length();i++){
    g2.drawLine(x1, y, x1 + 20, y);
    x1 += 50;
   }
  }

  // head
  if (x == 5 || x < 5){
   g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5.0f));
   g2.drawOval(135, 85, 35, 35);
  }

  // body
  if (x == 4 || x < 4){
   g2.drawLine(150, 120, 150, 190);
  }

  // left arm
  if (x == 3 || x < 3){
   g2.drawLine(150, 140, 125, 155); 
  }

  // right arm
  if (x == 2 || x < 2){
   g2.drawLine(150, 140, 175, 155); 
  }

  // left leg and foot
  if (x == 1 || x < 1){
   g2.drawLine(150, 190, 125, 200); // leg
   g2.drawLine(125, 200, 120, 190); // foot
  }

  // right leg and foot
  if (x == 0){
   g2.drawLine(150, 190, 175, 200); // leg
   g2.drawLine(175, 200, 180, 190); // foot
  }

  // Show whole word on screen
  if (x == 20){

   int x1 = 3; int y = 317;

   String temp = "";

   for (int i = 0; i < theWord.length(); i++){
    if ( letterList.contains(theWord.substring(i, i+1)) == true){
     temp += theWord.substring(i, i+1);
    }
    else{
     temp += " ";
    }
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < temp.length() ;i++){
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 25);
    g2.setFont(font);
    g2.drawString(temp.substring(i, i+1), x1, y);
    x1 += 50;
   }


   x1 = 3;  y = 370;
   for (int i = 0; i < letterList.size() ;i++){

    if (theWord.contains(letterList.get(i)) == false){
     g2.drawString(letterList.get(i), x1, y );
     x1 += 50;
    }

   }


  }
 }
}

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;


public class PlayHangman {

 /**
  * @param args
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  HangmanJFrame window = new HangmanJFrame();
  window.setVisible(true);

 }
}
```

Comment: Hasn't it that good old homework smell ? Hopefully, user557240 was kind enough to send us only the relevnt part of this code, which allows me to say "You really should consider reading http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx"

Comment: @Riduidel - Your link says "access denied" to me.

Comment: @hvgotcodes I think your full of fail.  You never even gave me a  chance to format my code properly.

Comment: Damn ! Then search for "Writing the perfect question - Jon Skeet: Coding Blog"

Comment: Besides, i'm particularly happy to have edited this question to make the source code legible, only to find, less than five minutes after, that it has reverted to this ... thing.

Comment: @Everyone - Keep it civil, please. The phrase "this question is full of fail" is not nearly as helpful as, "please format your code and provide us with an example of the part that does not work."

Comment: Hi user557240, I tried running your code, but it doesn't really seem to work. I can start the program, but I can just add letters, if I'm clicking on "Play again".

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to format it before hvgotcodes bumped in. So my problem is, whenever I remove my panel which has the graphic of the man and then try to add it to the Jframe again, the panel keeps shifting a few pixels to the left everytime it is remove.

Comment: @user557240, sorry, it frustrating when reading a question to see hundreds of lines of unformatted code with no real question.  A lot of posts here, that is all that is ever posted, and moreover, you can format the code to begin with.  Since you now have a real question with real and formatted code, I retract my 'full of fail' statement and wish you the best of luck in figuring it out.

Comment: for starters, you have 'unchecked' warnings from the compiler.  It won't fix your problem, but you should define ArrayLists like this:  ArrayList<String> usedLetters = new ArrayList<String>();  Don't forget the type in the actual constructor call.

Comment: @hvgotcodes Sorry to you too, it's just I'm new to the forum and had to read up on formatting code. I should have done this before I posted.

Comment: @user557240 accepted.  Civility has been restored. ;)

Comment: I've uploaded a pdf of what is happening. I have tried update/revalidate but it's still causing the same problem. http://www.sendspace.com/file/7vtlip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't remove and add the panel.  Just change the variable that stores the lives left and force a repaint.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but if I do this, a new panel is just added directly below the previous one.

Comment: Then that means your are still adding a panel.

Comment: Hi, can't get it to work. This is what I've tried  else{
     numLives = numLives - 1;
     line = new LinePanel(numLives,theWord,correctLetters);
     line.repaint();
     centerPanel.revalidate();
     repaint();
    }

Comment: Don't create a new LinePanel.  Just adjust the values.

Answer (score 1):

Although I couldn't really test with your code I have two vague ideas:

1. Keep in mind, that updates of swing and/or awt components should always be executed in the correct thread. Consider some tests with `invokeLater`:

   ```
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   // do your display modifications here
               }
   });
   ```
2. You could try to use `invalidate`/`validate` on your panels, that might help java to realize, that something changed.

I hope this helps solving your problem - good luck!